# Mysql fail to install for visual studio

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

As my title says it all. I had a problem with installing Mysql for Visual studio.
As this messages pops up all the time i open the installer.
At first I was installing the full developer package from the Mysql installer and it had fails to install
for Visual studio, so i downloaded the solo installer for that part and it still fails.
Notes: I have Visual studio 2019 community edition, and I am downloading MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.9
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM6Pa.png)

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio do you have installed?

Comment: I have Visual studio 2019 community edition, and I am downloading MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.9

Comment: Maybe you are missing Connector/NET. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-install.html <- they recommend using the Mysql installer instead